# xarray - resample daily input data to half-yearly data with leap year

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a daily input data in xarray for a leaf year (e.g. 1972) and would like to resample them into half-yearly data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('1972-01-01', freq='D', periods=366)    # a leap year
ds = xr.Dataset({'foo': ('time', np.arange(366)), 'time': time})
```

`ds` output:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 366)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1972-01-01 1972-01-02 ... 1972-12-31
Data variables:
    foo      (time) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365
```

Here is the resample function I used to get sum of the foo in every half a year (6 months):

```
res = ds['foo'].resample(time='6MS', closed='left').sum('time')
```

res output:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'foo' (time: 3)>
array([16471., 50324.,    nan])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1972-01-01 1972-07-01 1973-01-01
```

I was expecting the time coordiantes to have 1972-01-01 and 1972-07-01. Is this a bug for the resample function?

Comment: perhaps a bug, note is also the case for pandas Series' resample... related and also perculiar `df1["foo"].resample('6M', closed='left').sum()` and `ds['foo'].resample(time='6M', closed='left').sum('time')` include non null 1973 values.

Comment: Thanks @AndyHayden

Answer (score 1):

It has been identified as known issue and can be fixed by upgrading pandas.

```
pip3.exe install pandas --upgrade
```